# Searching the Nested file

Tags: asp.net

How to serach for file inside nested folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a recursive method like this....

```
    public string SearchForFile(string directory, string filename)
    {
        string file = "";

        //Look in this directory first
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, filename);
        if (files.Count() > 0)
            file = files[0];
        else  //Not found here, so try the sub-directories
        {
            foreach (string subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
            {
                file = SearchForFile(subDirectory, filename);
                if (file != "")
                    break;
            }
        }

        return file;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in C#:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974

The key is recursion. Your method has to call itself for each folder it finds. So it will go deeper and deeper into the call stack but only calling itself. For example, consider you have a folder `a` with folders `aa` and `ab` inside. These folders have folders `aaa` and `aba` inside them. You will then first loop through all contents of `a`, which is `aa` and `ab`. You will then call the same method and do the same thing for both of them, until there are no more folders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

as says in MSDN for [SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx)

```
Includes the current directory and all the subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points like mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.
```